# Do we really need Firefox tags for every version?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I just stumbled upon a tag wiki edit for Firefox 18. That made me search for Firefox tags on the site. Do we really need a [separate tag for all the different version of Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-*)?

We currently have (including the number of questions):

[firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) (3062), [firefox-3](/questions/tagged/firefox-3) (90), [firefox-5](/questions/tagged/firefox-5) (33), [firefox-8](/questions/tagged/firefox-8) (6), [firefox-9](/questions/tagged/firefox-9) (8), [firefox-10](/questions/tagged/firefox-10) (5), [firefox-12](/questions/tagged/firefox-12) (4), [firefox-16](/questions/tagged/firefox-16) (4) and [firefox-18](/questions/tagged/firefox-18) (0)

I do understand there may be some specific bugs in a certain version, but this looks like overkill. What should we do about these tags? Retag all to firefox and cleanup the crap questions while we are at it?

Comment: Are the tags somehow wrong? Do the questions tagged with it not relate to only that specific version?

Comment: I am not able to be 100% sure of my judging (hence my question here), but a lot of question either target the current version of FF at the time or are targeting firefox in general. @Bart

Comment: Firefox 3 might almost be worth a tag (3.6 particularly) but yeah, the changes between the rest are extremely minor compared to say IE. It's almost, but not quite, in the same boat as Chrome, where you can expect most people are using the latest version after so many months. 3.6 is a possible exception as some people still swear by it, and it *is* significantly different from the rapidly released versions

Answer (score 9):

No, we don't need a tag for every version of Firefox.

Back in the day, Firefox was releasing major versions slowly and there were big differences between the few existing versions. It took 4 years for version 2, 3 and 4 to be released. At that point, there were big differences between versions and the tags may have been relevant (although I don't see a tag for 2 or 4, so maybe not).

Nowadays, Firefox is using a ["rapid release"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Rapid_release) tactic which basically cranks out a new major version ever six weeks. I think we're at version 18 now (I ended up jumping ship for Chrome). However, like Chrome, FF auto-updates which means that the chances of someone getting stuck using some random version are small.

I would dump all the Firefox version tags completely and just have one. The OP can specify version number in the post body.

It should be quick, easy work to go through and manually remove the tags if everyone agrees.

Internet Explorer on the other hand is a totally different beast, and having tags for the version number is important. I know it seems weird to make exceptions, but that's kinda how it is.

Comment: Bet you jumped ship for Chrome for reasons other than ridiculous rapid release cycles, right? :P

Comment: Actually that's exactly why. I wasn't happy with the speed at which new versions of Firefox were released. Chrome releases them much faster. Higher version number === better product, right?

Comment: I hated the release cycles causing all my addons to suddenly stop working.  Having said that I'm using Firefox now because the main addon I use (Roboform) doesn't work very well with Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with version tags, but I don't think the solution is just outright getting rid of them.  We do need a solution, but since tag hierarchies have been disallowed, I'm not sure how to get there.  I agree with Wesley somewhat, that we could eliminate them just for Firefox, but I think a bracketed approach would be better if someone can determine where the lines are to draw.

For example: [firefox-pre-v4](/questions/tagged/firefox-pre-v4), [firefox-v4-v6](/questions/tagged/firefox-v4-v6), etc.  Something along those lines.

Comment: I was thinking the same. We'd just have to figure out a name that's more intuitive/discoverable/etc.

Comment: Don't forget that there are [extended support releases](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/), which complicates versioning somewhat.

Comment: I agree that there is a problem with version tags, but I really don’t know what to do about them. It’s getting so you almost have to use wildcards for any tag you care about, because people keep making new tags with slightly different versions affixed to them. Somebody should come up with a [SEDE query like for plural tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2666/most-common-tags-with-singular-and-plural-version-s-plural) but which show which tags have the most version tags. I have no SQL fu, but it is an interesting problem.